# Compare calendar object to get difference in seconds

Tags: java, datetime

I'm trying to get the difference in seconds of two calendar objects.

The first calendar object ist the current calling time, the second calendar object is an creation timestamp of an item.

Now I would like to know if the 'creation timestamp + some seconds' are later or before the current calling time calendar objects datetime.

```
Calendar referenceCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar compareCalendar = obj.getCreationDate();
compareCalendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, obj.getDuaration());
long differenceInSeconds = (compareCalendar.getTimeInMillis() - referenceCalendar.getTimeInMillis()) / 1000;

if (differenceInSeconds == 0) {
    iter.remove();
} else if (differenceInSeconds > 0) {
    iter.remove();
}
```

But the results are always "difference > 0".
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Any help would be grateful.

**EDIT**

I figured out that the calendar object "obj.getCreationDate()" will continuously update their datetime.

The method is really simple:

```
public void setCreationDate(Calendar date)
            throws InvalidParameterException {
        if (date == null) {
            throw new InvalidParameterException(
                    "Creation date can not be null.");
        } else {
            this.creationDate = date;
        }
    }
```

And the method will be only 1 time called:

> setCreationDate(Calendar.getInstance);

Will Calendar.getInstance force my saved var to update their datetime?
It seems to me that this happens.

-> I'm really sure that my method really be called only one time

Comment: Do you *have* to use java.util.*? Joda Time is a *much* nicer API for this sort of thing.

Comment: No, it's just my first choice. It has to run with android 4.0 +

Answer (score 2):

Calendar is comparable, don't get the milliseconds and compare, use `compareCalendar.compareTo(referenceCalendar)`

In your case:

```
Calendar referenceCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar compareCalendar = obj.getCreationDate();
compareCalendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, obj.getDuaration());

if (compareCalendar.compareTo(referenceCalendar) >= 0) {
    // ccompareCalendar is equals or greater referenceCalendar
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Aviram.
I think my problem is that my compareCalendar update it's datetime. But I don't know why-

Answer (score 0):

Problem found:

its the following line:

> compareCalendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, obj.getDuaration());

If you add some fields to an existing calendar object, the base object is overwritten by the current datetime object + the field you added.

I don't know if it is by design or just a bug.

So you can simply clone your object and work with it instead of obj.getCreationTime()

> Calendar clonedCalendar = (Calendar) obj.getCreationDate().clone();